# Re: Expander control in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, controls, expander

I have installed the latest silverlight toolkit and dragged the expander control onto my design, there is some kind of an error going around with the name spaces, and my intellisense stopped to work after I added the control, following is the xmlns that is added to the application when I dragged the control onto the xaml editor:

xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"

Can anyone please identify why would this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since you posted your question, but in the case you still have the problem, I tell you that I had it too and it was a conflict in versions. In Silverlight 4, controls of the toolkit are integrated to the framework. And your *xmlns:toolkit* should reference a dll, not a http uri.
My problem was I was using RC version of Blend. So I advise you to check your VS2010, Blend and Silverlight version to make sure they're aligned.

bye